# Show even null values in case query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions

How would i show even null values in this query:

```
select 
case floor(reading_winddirection / 45)
    when 0 then 'N'
    when 1 then 'NE'
    when 2 then 'E'
    when 3 then 'SE'
    when 4 then 'S'
    when 5 then 'SW'
    when 6 then 'W'
    when 7 then 'NW'
end windgroup,
count(*) cnt,
round(100 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over()) percentage 
from simulation_readings  
group by windgroup
```

Now the query returns ie:

```
 N  66  66
 E  2   2
SE  1   1
SW  1   1
```

But i wish it to return all cases even if they have no values and set them to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want a `left join` with a fixed list if values

```
select 
    d.windgroup,
    count(s.reading_winddirection) cnt,
    coalesce(round(
        100 * count(s.reading_winddirection) 
        / nullif(sum(count(s.reading_winddirection)) over(), 0)
    ), 0) percentage 
from (
    select 0 n, 'N' windgroup
    union all select 1, 'NE'
    union all select 2, 'E'
    union all select 3, 'SE' 
    union all select 4, 'S'
    union all select 5, 'SW'
    union all select 6, 'W'
    union all select 7, 'NW'
) d
left join simulation_readings s 
    on  floor(s.reading_winddirection / 45) = d.n
group by d.windgroup
```

In MySQL < 8.0, this would look like:

```
select 
    d.windgroup,
    coalesce(c.cnt, 0) cnt,
    coalesce(round(100 * c.cnt, 0 / nullif(t.total, 0)), 0) percentage 
from (
    select 0 n, 'N' windgroup
    union all select 1, 'NE'
    union all select 2, 'E'
    union all select 3, 'SE' 
    union all select 4, 'S'
    union all select 5, 'SW'
    union all select 6, 'W'
    union all select 7, 'NW'
) d
cross join (select count(*) total from simulation_readings) t
left join ( 
    select floor(reading_winddirection / 45) n, count(*) cnt
    from simulation_readings  
    group by n
) c on c.n = d.n
group by d.windgroup
```

Comment: I get an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(), 0)
    ), 0) percentage
from (
    select 0 n, 'N' windgroup
    union ' at line 6

Comment: @stacks: this works fine in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=813fd211447e75fdb04e1fb1742a651b). Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.28-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server - (GPL)

Comment: @stacks: but the query you started your question with doesn't run on MySQL 5.7 (it runs on MySQL 8.0 only). Anyway, I updated my answer with a solution that should work in your version.

Comment: Yes, i guess i copied the wrong query while trying on my local and on remote server. Now i get: Unknown column 'windgroup' in 'group statement'